# Is there a service or db to download or convert Postal Codes to Geo-Shapes / Polygons?

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding, postal-code

I'm looking for a service that converts Postal Code of Major European Cities to Geo Shapes (List of Lat/Lng) pairs like when you go to Google Maps and type for examples 10557 Berlin, and it draws boundaries around the are for that Geo-Code.

I found some Hacky ways to use the official Maps for this, But I don't wanna rely on that. is there a paid service or downloadable files that has such data.

Given that I don't want Postal Code to (1 Center Point Lat/Lng) but instead to a lit of points to form the shape for that Postal Code.

Comment: @mapperz I'm not quite sure this is a duplicate, despite the tags. It seems more similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146985/ and some of the questions linked there, only for European cities rather than the US. I read this as seeking postal code boundary polygons, not necessarily geocoding an address or getting an address for a point.